# Create WAV file for each record in database

Tags: php, mysql, wav

I have table in database in which I'm storing `wav` files in `longblob` column. 
I'm trying to create an folder and store all `wav`'s of given user on the server. What I have so far is query to database and table and so far simple example of storing just one `wav`. I'm not much familiar with PHP and I'll need a little bit help on this.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxx","testDB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT recording FROM users WHERE accountID = '1234'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row)) {

    $data = $result["recording"];

    //mkdir('/var/spool/sounds/', 0755, true);

    $wavFileName = "/var/spool/sounds/wavfile.wav";
    $fh = fopen($wavFileName, 'w'); 
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

The snipped above is creating one `wav` in that directory.

If user has 5 saved wav files, how to create directory with name `userID` and `file1.wav`, `file2.wav` .. etc inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the path and filename with concatenation of userid and number of files already created. Then, check if that path exists, otherwise create it.

```
$directory = "/var/spool/sounds/" . $userID;
$fileExtension = ".wav";
$fileNumber = 1;
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row))
{
    $data = $result["recording"];
    if (!is_dir($directory))
        mkdir($directory, 0755, true);

    $wavFileName = $directory . "/file" . $fileNumber;
    /*
     *  if you need to check if the file already exists,
     *  you can rename the new file "/var/spool/sounds/userId/file1_copy.wav"
     *  or "/var/spool/sounds/userId/file1_copy_copy.wav" if a copy already exists and so on.
     */
    while (file_exists($wavFileName . $fileExtension))
        $wavFileName .= "_copy";
    $fh = fopen($wavFileName . $fileExtension, 'w'); 
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
    $fileNumber++;
}
```

Comment: maybe is better to create the user folder outside/before the while loop ?

Comment: @Pierre What if, for some reasons, the folder is deleted while looping?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just one question. What will happen if user has `file1.wav` saved in his directory, then the file is deleted from database and later is saved new one in database with that name. This will override the file in directory, right?

Comment: @Ivanov yes it will be

Comment: Then I'll need to check if the file is already exist. Can you show me simple example?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My solution blindly appends an incremented number to the file name. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, will work :

```
$account_id = 1234;
mkdir('/var/spool/sounds/'.$account_id, 0755, true);
$sql="SELECT recording FROM users WHERE accountID = ".$account_id ;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$i=0;
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row)) {
    $i++;
    $data = $result["recording"];

    $wavFileName = "/var/spool/sounds/".$account_id."/file".$i.".wav";
    $fh = fopen($wavFileName, 'w'); 
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}
```